# How can I write an updated array into a PHP file

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building something in PHP which reads from a PHP file, which looks like this:

```php
<?php

return [
'name' => 'John Smith'
];
```

In my code, I'm getting the contents of the file and I'm reading it. But here's my problem. When I want to add an item to that array, I can but I'm not sure how to save it back into that array file.

I've tried these ways of doing it ($array being the updated array)

```
file_put_contents('file.php', var_export($array, true));
```

```
file_put_contents('file.php', print_r($array, true));
```

Comment: Hmmm what is `return_r()` when it is at home with its boots off?

Comment: Check what `var_export($array, true)` actually gives you, then figure out which missing parts around it you have to add yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see @misorude already suggested you need parameter 2 of `var_export` to be set to true as below

```
$ids = ['t1'=>10, 't2'=> 12, 't3' => 5];

$str = '<?php ' . PHP_EOL
        . 'return '
        . var_export($ids, 1) . ';' ;

echo $str;
```

RESULT:

```
<?php 
return array (
  't1' => 10,
  't2' => 12,
  't3' => 5,
);
```

So just write $str to a file and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Put back the array in your file using `var_export()` like this :

`file_put_contents('file.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';');`